# Consuming Paginated REST API

Tags: rest, go, pagination

I am trying to consume an API that on each successful request has a json key like the following:

```
{
    "hasNextPage": true,
    "endCursor": "some_guid_present_here"
}
```

The way the API works (I have used it many times in Python but am trying with Go for separate use case) is to basically check if there is a next page, then use the appropriate cursor to continue to paginate.

However, every time I use this structure, it will sometimes keep looping even though the `response.Paginations.HasNextPage` will be false.

I am trying to understand if it is my structure of consuming a paginated API like this that is causing this or else.

Also, I have say 4-5 requests to start off with, which I sent separately via goroutines. I am not sure if this is causing an issue but I've attached that as well in `etl.go`.

The main request making structs are in `api.go`.

I've confirmed that I do receive responses and they are unmarshaling properly, but am trying to wrangle this uncertain behavior.

api.go

```
package models


import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

type Request struct {
    Url string
    ApiKey string
}

type Response struct {
    ...some fields...
    Paginations Pagination `json:"pagination"`
}

type Pagination struct {
    EndCursor   string `json:"endCursor"`
    HasNextPage bool   `json:"hasNextPage"`
}


func (request *Request) Get() ([]Response, error) {
    
    var responses []Response
    var response Response

    // Set up new request
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", request.Url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating request...")
        return responses, err
    }

    // Add request headers
    req.Header = http.Header{
        "accept":        {"application/json"},
        "authorization": {"Bearer " + request.ApiKey},
    }

    // Get our initial response from the API and capture status code
    resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    response.Status = resp.StatusCode

    // Read the response body and Unmarshal into struct
    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    json.Unmarshal(respBody, &response)

    // If there was a parsing error, log it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    
    // This field will be in the response payload
    // It is verified to be of type bool (not string)
    fmt.Printf("Has Next Page? %t\n", resp.Paginations.HasNextPage)

    // Append response to our slice of responses
    responses = append(responses, response)

    // If paginations are available, continue to loop through until all paginations are exhausted
    for response.Paginations.HasNextPage == true {
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", request.Url, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return responses, err
        }

        // Append "after" cursor to query in order to redirect to paginated response
        qry := req.URL.Query()
        qry.Set("after", response.Paginations.EndCursor)
        req.URL.RawQuery = qry.Encode()
        fmt.Println("Paginated request query: ", req.URL.String())

        // Make request
        resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
        response.Status = resp.StatusCode
        fmt.Printf("Status Code: %d\n", response.Status)

        // Read response and deserialize it
        respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        json.Unmarshal(respBody, &response)
        fmt.Println("Pagination Cursor: ", response.Paginations.EndCursor)
        fmt.Printf("Has Next Page? %t\n", response.Paginations.HasNextPage)

        // If there was a parsing error, log it
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        // Append response to our slice of responses
        responses = append(responses, response)
    }
    return responses, nil


}
```

etl.go

```
package models

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Etl struct {
    Requests []Request
}

func (etl *Etl) Extract() [][]Response {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan []Response)
    defer close(ch)
    for _, req := range etl.Requests {
        wg.Add(1) // Increment
        fmt.Println("Incremented wait group")
        go func(i Request) {
            defer wg.Done() // Decrement
            resp, err := req.Get()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            ch <- resp
            fmt.Println("Decremented wait group")
        }(req)
    }

    results := make([][]Response, len(etl.Requests))
    for i, _ := range results {
        results[i] = <-ch
        //fmt.Println(results[i])
    }
    wg.Wait()
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the issue. In my pagination loop `for response.Paginations.HasNextPage == true` I was creating a new request object (`http.NewRequest`) on each iteration which did not have headers added from the prior (initial request).

This caused a 401 unauthorized error to return and continuous querying of the API since it was not receiving a new `response.Paginations.HasNextPage` value.

My solution was to simply alter the for loop a bit like so:

```
package models


import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

type Request struct {
    Url string
    ApiKey string
}

type Response struct {
    ...some fields...
    Paginations Pagination `json:"pagination"`
}

type Pagination struct {
    EndCursor   string `json:"endCursor"`
    HasNextPage bool   `json:"hasNextPage"`
}


func (request *Request) Get() ([]Response, error) {
    
    var responses []Response
    var response Response

    // Set up new request
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", request.Url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating request...")
        return responses, err
    }

    // Add request headers
    req.Header = http.Header{
        "accept":        {"application/json"},
        "authorization": {"Bearer " + request.ApiKey},
    }

    // Get our initial response from the API and capture status code
    resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    response.Status = resp.StatusCode

    // Read the response body and Unmarshal into struct
    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    json.Unmarshal(respBody, &response)

    // If there was a parsing error, log it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    
    // This field will be in the response payload
    // It is verified to be of type bool (not string)
    fmt.Printf("Has Next Page? %t\n", resp.Paginations.HasNextPage)

    // Append response to our slice of responses
    responses = append(responses, response)

    // If paginations are available, continue to loop through until all paginations are exhausted
    for response.Paginations.HasNextPage == true {

        // Append "after" cursor to query in order to redirect to paginated response
        qry := req.URL.Query()
        qry.Set("after", response.Paginations.EndCursor)
        req.URL.RawQuery = qry.Encode()
        fmt.Println("Paginated request query: ", req.URL.String())

        // Make request
        resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
        response.Status = resp.StatusCode
        fmt.Printf("Status Code: %d\n", response.Status)

        // Read response and deserialize it
        respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        json.Unmarshal(respBody, &response)
        fmt.Println("Pagination Cursor: ", response.Paginations.EndCursor)
        fmt.Printf("Has Next Page? %t\n", response.Paginations.HasNextPage)

        // If there was a parsing error, log it
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        // Append response to our slice of responses
        responses = append(responses, response)
    }
    return responses, nil


}
```